# Flagging rude question and comments by a newbie

Tags: discussion, flags, new-users

I don't know how to deal with rude questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33854035/841108) (downvoted -7); I gave an (imperfect, but useful, and upvoted +4) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33854063/841108) and I find the reactions of the OP insulting.

Both the OP and I edited several times (OP edited, per requests, his question, and I incrementally edited my answer to improve it).

Surprisingly, the OP does not understand my answer (which had many links to IMHO useful external references) and did not improve his question to be meaningful enough.

I flagged the most insulting comment (and the edited question), but I don't see any flags.

At the very least, I am surprised to not see my own flags. I very rarely flag questions or comments (and the last time I did, IIRC the flags where visible to me).

Perhaps submitted flags should be as visible to the flag submitter as are upvotes, etc. Seeing them is useful (at the very least to avoid trying flagging several times the same thing).

Comment: What do you mean *"I don't see any flags"*? You aren't a moderator, so if other people have flagged you won't see them.

Comment: Again, I am flagging *very rarely*, but in my imperfect memory a flag remains visible when I put it. Perhaps I am wrong, I flag usually once or twice every half-year at most.

Comment: Do you mean you can't see the flag you raised in your own profile? Try [`http://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/<your ID>`](http://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/841108)

Comment: I see them there, but I thought (probably wrongly) that the flag was visible to the flagging user near the comment or the answer or the question. If it is not, I believe it should be a useful feature.

Comment: You'll see a red flag instead of the grey one when you mouse over a *comment* you've flagged, but AFAIK there's no indication if you've flagged the *question*.

Comment: If you try to flag again, then the options you can't use will be greyed out. Not perfect, but the information is there.

Comment: That op has perhaps among the most bizarre programmer personalities I've ever encountered -- going from a request for basically a portable exception-handling solution to arguing in assembly terms about the cost of long jumps (many of which are imagined), and then ending on a monologue about whether it's worth the effort to write his own compiler. My condolences!

Comment: @Ike: I saw the question but did not dare to join in on the disucssion. It appears to me as an extreme case of "X-Y Problem Solving": OP has some problem (and it's quite unclear to me what that is) and came up with a bizarre and thoroughly non-standard possible 'solution', then tried to wrestle C into fitting this solution. Oh - and then make it Portable please.

Comment: you can replace most of the first half of this question with "I flagged a question". I thought you were asking if you were right in flagging the person

Comment: ugh, this represents everything i hate about *how experienced users handle newbie questions*.  a new user attempts to ask a question, and the response is a barrage of downvotes and comments that he "makes no sense."  no wonder he was so upset!  there was no effort whatsoever on anyone's part to try to understand the OP's point of view in order to resolve the mutual misunderstanding.  the downvote is by far the worst feature of SO.

Comment: @dbliss: I respectfully disagree. I tried to understand the OP's question (which he did not motivate enough; motivations in questions is *very* important). I incrementally edited my answer to adapt ...

Comment: the fact that your ridiculously over-long answer got so many upvotes is the clearest evidence i've ever seen of the witch-burning crowd mentality that prevails whenever this sort of disagreement happens.  a bunch of users who saw this meta post rushed to upvote your answer -- i would bet my house that fewer than 10% read it.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch fair enough.  i don't blame you.  i blame the crowd effect.  the OP was overwhelmed and responded from that position of being attacked by a ton of people at once (via downvotes).

Comment: @dbliss: On that I probably agree. In general, it is quite strange that the answers I put the most efforts in are *not* those which have been upvoted a lot.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch same here.  overall, i think you as an individual did a commendable job here.

Comment: @dbliss: You taught me a new English word. That is probably the first time I'm reading "commendable". I had no idea what that meant (and of course STFW)

Comment: However, regarding OP, he was insulting and I don't think that was right. In general, I believe newscomers (or old SO contributors alike) should never be hurt or upset when asking to improve their question. Making a good question is hard (in general), and there is nothing wrong in improving it

Comment: @Laurel Why are you bumping a 6-month-old question to the front page?

Answer (score 15):

As noted in the comments above, you can look at the flags you've raised in your profile. The flags you raised appear to have been addressed and the post has been locked due to the unconstructive activity on it.

As for what else to do about a question like this, IMHO this is a classic example of why one should *not* attempt to answer unclear or overly broad questions. It's a great way to waste your time, and raise the ire of someone who couldn't be bothered to write a good question in the first place.

For all I know, you might have written the best answer ever to whatever the OP was asking. But if the original question isn't focused or clear enough to be appropriate on Stack Overflow, it's unlikely your answer would be appropriate either (indeed, it's quite a lengthy treatise, well beyond the detail of the usual *programming* questions that Stack Overflow is meant for).

Beyond that though, if the original question is so poor as to deserve being heavily downvoted, it's probably also not good enough for someone to be able to answer it well with confidence that they are addressing what the OP intends to ask. This sets you up for a protracted back-and-forth with the OP, something that often leads to tempers flaring.

I'm sorry that you found yourself in this situation. I have to admit, I'm surprised that someone with your experience and reputation on Stack Overflow got suckered into the situation with this particular person. I guess you've just been luckier than most during your tenure here so far. :)